# How to replace/substitute part of the url with variable, using Python/Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace part of the following URL with string from a variable:
`https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/05/data`
How I can exclude some groups and use only one.

This is what I did:

```
def change(var_data):
  var = str(var_data) // for example: 11
  url = 'https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/05/data'
  url2 = re.sub(r'(\d\d)', var, url)
  print(url2)
```

The print looks like this: `https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/1111/11/data`
and it is wrong because I need to change only `05 to 11`, not `2018 to 1111`

other version:

```
data_url_2 = re.sub(r'.+/(\d\d)/.+', month, data_url)
print(data_url_2)
```

print = '11'

I was thinking of finding the way to make 3 groups and exclude first and the third one:

```
data_url_2 = re.sub(r'(.+/\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(/.+)', month, data_url)
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b\d{2}\b', '11', url)`?

Comment: _this is wrong because I need to change only 05 to 11, not 2018 to 1111_ It's not wrong.  `20` matches `\d\d`, and `18` also matches `\d\d`.  Did you mean to say "this isn't what I wanted" instead of "wrong"?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: re.sub(r'\b\d{2}\b', '11', url)?  - i can't use '11' it has to be string from var.

Comment: gmds, I want to change month in the url from "05" to month from variable - var.

Comment: Do you really need to use regex or would it work with a different approach?

Comment: He definitely doesn't need regex but let's do it anyway. `re.sub('/[\d]{2}/', '/11/', url)` OR `re.sub('(?<=/)[\d]{2}(?=/)', '11', url)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't need regex but let's do it anyway.

```
>>> import re

>>> url = 'https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/05/data'


>>> re.sub('/[\d]{2}/', '/11/', url)
'https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/11/data'


>>> re.sub('(?<=/)[\d]{2}(?=/)', '11', url)
'https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/11/data'
```

.

.

> I was thinking of finding the way to make 3 groups and exclude first and the third one:

**What?**

Comment: positive lookbehind and positive lookahead (?<=/)(?=/) that helped, thank you very much, I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

One way without regex

```
def change(var_data):
  var = str(var_data)
  url = 'https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/05/data'
  url1 = url.split('/')
  url2 = '/'.join(url1[:-2] + [var] + [url1[-1]])
  print(url2)

change('11')
#https://somedomain.eu/api/one/some/2018/11/data
```